# How to rotate symbol in each point of LineString?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a linestring, and want to draw arrow forward and arrow back in each point except firat and last. Like this [image]

I have no problems with first and last point couse i can rotate arrows with `startAngle` and `endAngle`. But how can i rotate arrows for other points?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function that can do this for you. You can either break your line in to simple segments for the purposes of styling or [write your own function](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html) (based on [StartAngle](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/FilterFunction_startAngle.java))

Comment: Okey, i can slice LineString on segments and return this collection of segments back to style. But i don't understand what i can do with this segments in my sld.